# Sample an unevenly distributed set for training

Tags: random, machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

I'm training an SGD neural net classifier on a very imbalanced training dataset. To compensate for underepresentated classes, I perform actual training on a set randomly sampled s.t. classes with fewer examples get picked more often.

What is a principled way to pick the volume of the latter set vs the number of epochs it will be run on? Advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I perform actual training on a set randomly sampled s.t. classes with fewer examples get picked more often

Random sampling does not assure a higher representation from the under-represented class; as the name implies, the selection would be random.

---

***The question has a broad scope for answers.***

There's no silver bullet way to increase the representation from the under-represented class while ensuring a good model performance. Some basic things to try would be,

1. **Under Sampling:** Removing some over-represented instances (provided you have enough data)
2. **Over Sampling:** Make copies of the under-represented instances

To answer your question on the number of epochs to train on:

Once you get a balanced data set by one of the above methods, you perform training on it as if it is a balanced data set.

---

**P.S.**
Please note that the above is not the only way to tackle a skewed data set. Many more factors like evaluation metrics and trying out different hypotheses come in to play.